# Linked list using C

Tags: c, list, linked-list

I am trying to create a linked list that at each node has a pointer to a separate linked list of different type. Here is what is going wrong, the first list (X) is creating just fine but I am creating one linked list (Y) that all nodes of X point to instead of each node of X pointing to a unique Y. I hope that made sense. Here is the code that I have:

```
struct PathNodeStruct {
  char CurrentPathMovement;
  struct PathNodeStruct * prev;
  struct PathNodeStruct * next;
};
typedef struct PathNodeStruct PathNode;
typedef struct PathNodeStruct * PathNodePtr;
struct PathNodeStruct * head = NULL;

struct RoomNodeStruct {
  int roomNumber;
  struct PathNode * pathStart;
  struct RoomNodeStruct * next;
};
typedef struct RoomNodeStruct RoomNode;
typedef struct RoomNodeStruct * RoomNodePtr;
struct RoomNodeStruct * roomHead = NULL;

void insertPathNode(char move){
if(head == NULL){   //case if first node in list
    head = (PathNodePtr)malloc(sizeof(PathNode));
    if(head != NULL){
        head->CurrentPathMovement = move;   //sets data in node
        head->prev = NULL; //sets links up
        head->next = NULL;
    } else{
        printf("ERROR");
        }
} else{
    PathNodePtr cursorPtr = head;
    while(cursorPtr->next != NULL){   //cursors to end of list
        cursorPtr = cursorPtr->next;
    }
    PathNodePtr newPathNodePtr = (PathNodePtr)malloc(sizeof(PathNode)); //allocates for node to be added
    if(newPathNodePtr != NULL){
        cursorPtr->next = newPathNodePtr;
        newPathNodePtr->prev = cursorPtr;   //sets links up
        newPathNodePtr->next = NULL;
        newPathNodePtr->CurrentPathMovement = move; //sets data in node
    } else{
        printf("ERROR");
    }
}


void insertRoomNode(int value){
if(roomHead == NULL){   //case if first node in list
    roomHead = (RoomNodePtr)malloc(sizeof(RoomNode));
    if(roomHead != NULL){
        roomHead->roomNumber = value;   //sets data in node
        roomHead->next = NULL;
        roomHead->pathStart = head;
    } else{
        printf("ERROR ALLOCATING IN INSERT ROOM NODE.");
        }
} else{
    RoomNodePtr cursorPtr = roomHead;
    while(cursorPtr->next != NULL){   //cursors to end of list
        cursorPtr = cursorPtr->next;
    }
    RoomNodePtr newRoomNodePtr = (RoomNodePtr)malloc(sizeof(RoomNode)); //allocates for node to be added
    if(newRoomNodePtr != NULL){
        cursorPtr->next = newRoomNodePtr;
        newRoomNodePtr->next = NULL;
        newRoomNodePtr->roomNumber = value; //sets data in node
        newRoomNodePtr->pathStart = head;
    } else{
        printf("ERROR ALLOCATING IN INSERT ROOM NODE.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this for a MUD server?

Comment: `roomHead->pathStart = head;` I think this is not necessary. Because `head` is global variable. There is no need to keep as separate members.

Comment: Not for a MUD server